# ng-repeat="(key, value) in item in arr"?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

**Obviously the above is syntactically invalid in AngularJs**, however, neither `item in array` nor `(key, value) in item` will do the trick on their own. Is there a way to combine the two into a single statement (like the above), or some other way of doing this?

I have map of key/value pairs that look like so:

```
$this.colorsHash = { 
  '05/04/2015': { sum: 540, color: 'rgb(176,145,219)' },
  '05/10/2015': { sum: 379, color: 'rgb(161,111,107)' },
  '05/13/2015': { sum: 429, color: 'rgb(173,138,118)' },
  '05/19/2015': { sum: 478, color: 'rgb(209,108,161)' },
  '05/15/2015': { sum: 596, color: 'rgb(200,200,196)' },
  '05/18/2015': { sum: 337, color: 'rgb(102,114,121)' } 
}
```

I am using this map to generate a legend, however, this legend could potentially have 20+ values, so I want to break it up into equal sized chunks and display them side-by-side. That part I have figured out. It creates an array of n arrays with equal length like so:

```
$this.splitArr = [ 
  [ 
    { '05/04/2015': { sum: 540, color: 'rgb(176,145,219)' } },
    { '05/10/2015': { sum: 379, color: 'rgb(161,111,107)' } },
    { '05/13/2015': { sum: 429, color: 'rgb(173,138,118)' } } 
  ],
  [ 
    { '05/19/2015': { sum: 478, color: 'rgb(209,108,161)' } },
    { '05/15/2015': { sum: 596, color: 'rgb(200,200,196)' } },
    { '05/18/2015': { sum: 337, color: 'rgb(102,114,121)' } } 
  ] 
]
```

My question is how to use ng-repeat over each key/value pair when it is nested within arrays. Here is the code that I am using that gets me each object, but I do not then know how to access the key/value from that object.

```
<ul style="list-style: none;" ng-repeat="item in Main.splitArr">
    <li ng-repeat="obj in item">
        <div style="height: 20px; width: 20px; 
            background-color: {{/*I need the object's value.color here*/}}; 
            display: inline-block;"></div> = 
        <span ng-bind="/*I need the object's key here*/"></span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Downvoters care to comment as to why "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to this was to slightly modify my `splitArr` structure. Rather than making it an `Array<Array<Object>>`, I made it an `Array<Object>`. That way, I can keep the equal groupings, but it also allows me to use `ng-repeat="obj in arr"` followed by an `ng-repeat="(key, value) in obj"`, like so:

```js
angular.module("myApp", [])
.controller("myCtrl", function () {
  var $this = this;
  $this.splitArr = [ 
    { 
       '05/04/2015': { sum: 540, color: 'rgb(176,145,219)' },
       '05/10/2015': { sum: 379, color: 'rgb(161,111,107)' },
       '05/13/2015': { sum: 429, color: 'rgb(173,138,118)' } 
    },
    { 
       '05/19/2015': { sum: 478, color: 'rgb(209,108,161)' },
       '05/15/2015': { sum: 596, color: 'rgb(200,200,196)' },
       '05/18/2015': { sum: 337, color: 'rgb(102,114,121)' } 
    } 
  ];
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl as Main">
<ul style="list-style: none; display: inline-block;" ng-repeat="item in Main.splitArr">
    <li ng-repeat="(key, value) in item">
        <div style="height: 20px; width: 20px; 
            background-color: {{value.color}}; 
            display: inline-block;"></div> = 
        <span ng-bind="key"></span>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<ul style="list-style: none;" ng-repeat="item in splitArr">
<li ng-repeat="(key,value) in filterSecId(item)">
    <div style="height: 20px; width: 20px; 
        background-color: {{value.color.color}}; 
        display: inline-block;"></div> = {{value.keyt}}
</li>
```

Update you html with this and add this in your controller

```
$scope.filterSecId = function(items) {
var result = {};
angular.forEach(items, function(value, key) {
    var val={
     "color":value[Object.keys(value)[0]],
     "keyt":Object.keys(value)[0]
    };
    result[key] = val;
});
return result;
}});
```

I have made few changes for this to work. Ingnore lack of best practices. Hope It will serve for your requirement. Thanks

Comment: Through a conversation with charlietfl, I did get my problem resolved by changing my data structure for splitArr, which is exactly what you are doing in the filter. This is definitely a legitimate solution, though - I didn't even think about using a filter. Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

Object syntax is documented in [ng-repeat docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat)

Try

```
ng-repeat="(key, value) in arr"
```

Comment: I must be missing something (or you are). Would be a lot simpler if you used arrays instead and a groupBy filter. Using unique property names is a lot more difficult to work with

Comment: So you mean rather than using the date as they key for an object, make it an array of objects, and make the date field a property on the object?

Comment: yes...will find consistent structures a lot easier to work with. Also objects have no order and filtering is a whole lots simpler also

Comment: Can you open up a chat channel? I am not opposed to changing it, but the structure is very intentional, and I may need to give you more information

Comment: feel free to invite me to one

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124346/discussion-between-mhodges-and-charlietfl).